# Plotting truncated normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot a [truncated Gaussian distribution (using scipy)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) with a mean of `0.5`, and a standard distribution of `1.0`. The distribution is truncated to be only in the interval `(0,1)`.

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
dist=truncnorm(a=0,b=1,loc=0.5, scale = 1.0)
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label='normalised truncated Gaussian')
```

However I get this instead:

[image]

Everything after `x=0.5` seems normal but below that you get a sudden dip to zero. However the distribution should only be zero outside of `(0,1)`. What is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling it to plot that way with `loc` which shifts the plot.

`dist=truncnorm(a=0,b=1,loc=0.5, scale = 1.0)` should be
`dist=truncnorm(a=0,b=1, scale = 1.0)` to get the standard plot.

From the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py) on truncnorm():

> For a uniform distribution MLE, the location is the minimum of the
>           data, and the scale is the maximum minus the minimum. (Line 6570)